# Visual Studio Extension dependency

Tags: visual-studio-2017, vsix, csproj

We're using Visual Studio 2017 in our team and we use certain extensions for certain projects. When adding a new extension to a project I want to make sure this is installed by the other developers if they work on that project.

So for example I added the Typewriter extension to auto generate .ts files. I would like to put a "dependency" on that extension so that when somebody opens the solution it would make sure that the developer knows to install the extension (if it's not installed).

This could be a build error, a popup or just an auto install, is there any way to do any of these actions?

Sending a team-wide email is not really monkey-proof. Most dev's wont install the extension (or even read the email) if they are currently not working on the project so this is not monkey-proof.

Comment: You could do something like this (clone or maybe you can use it out of box) https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=MadsKristensen.SuggestedExtensions

Comment: @ErikEJ sadly that extension is not available (yet) for Visual Studio 2017.

Comment: I've added an issue on the GitHub page: https://github.com/madskristensen/SolutionExtensions/issues/24

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use this extension: [Extension Manager 2017](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=MadsKristensen.ExtensionManager), the successor to [Suggested Extensions](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=MadsKristensen.SuggestedExtensions)

Comment: Yeah I got a link through GitHub, will mark your answer as valid so you get some points :)